# How do I call the no arg constructor after I have allready created an object of the class?

Tags: java, constructor

I create an object of the class:

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(2,4);
```

Which gives my rectangle and height of 2 and a width of 4.

But is there anyway I can call the no arg constructor later on in my code without creating a new object?

without doing this:

```
Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle();
```

Comment: Can you please elablorate on why you want to call a constructor and not have it "construct". I doubt it's possible, but knowing why you're trying to do it might help people answer your question with something that is both possible and sensible.

Comment: why do you want to call the constructor later on?  What is your final aim.

Comment: I want to call the no arg constructor because that initializes a rectangle with width = 1 and height = 1

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, do you want to change the dimensions of the current rectangle from whatever it was initialised to (ie the (2,4)) to (1,1)?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid creating a new object? Are there other instance variables in a `Rectangle` that you want to "keep"? And,for what it's worth, a no-arg constructor seems a bit smelly for this in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors by their definition create new objects.

If you no longer need `rec` you can do `rec = new Rectangle()` provided the Rectangle has no no arg constructor.

Or you just want to replace the values of the current rectangle? if so just change via setters for create a method to update both values...

Comment: rec = new Rectangle() called the no arg contstructor in the object I already created. 

Thanks!

Comment: No it didn't.  it created a new rectangle and assigned your variable holding your old rectangle to the new rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

Normally this is a sign that you need to refactor your constructors such that all the code which is common to two or more constructors is contained within a separate (non-constructor) method.

Answer (score 0):

no you cannot. You can use reflection for creating a new object without using new keyword, but i am not sure whether it calls a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the basic properties of your Object in a method and call that method in constructors

or

In your case use rec = null; rec = new Rectangle();// if you don't require Rectangle(2,4)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only call one constructor.

If you want to overwrite the coordinates you can use the `setBounds` method, e.g.

```
rec.setBounds(0,0,0,0);
```

But unless you're developing a mobile phone game, there's not much point in re-using the old rectangle, and it's simpler to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can, here is how

```
public class Example {
    //no arg constructor
    public Example() {
        //your code
    }
    //constructor with argument
    public Example(String arg) {
       //call the no arg constructor
       this();
       //do something else
    }
}
```